Cucumber windows Authentication login in MSSQL
Do I need to place sqljdbc_auth.dll in System32 to use Windows Authentication login in the Cucumber framework? I'm having issues with my connection to MSSQL using windows authentication in Cucumber framework
public class DbConnection {
    private String connectionUrl;
    private Connection connection;

    public DbConnection() {
        // Define the connection URL with integrated security
        connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=db;integratedSecurity=true;";
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            // Ensure that the JDBC driver is loaded
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}

We need permission to place any file in windows32 so if there is another way before asking for permission will be very helpful
